# onclick change the image source

Tags: javascript

I'm facing issue while changing the source of the image using `onclick`. It works when I use `getElementById` but not when `getElementsByClassName`.

Here's the bin...

```
<h1>Image swapping</h1>
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="image_swap"/><br>
<button onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('image_swap').src='http://via.placeholder.com/250x150'">Swap to smaller</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('image_swap').src='http://via.placeholder.com/350x150'">Swap to larger</button>
```

https://jsbin.com/gupabe/6/edit?html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document.GetElementsByClassName returns a list of elements (since you can have multiple things with the same classname)
adjust your code to pick the first one for a simple fix

https://jsbin.com/sevituduxu/1/edit?html,output

```
<button onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('image_swap')[0].src='http://via.placeholder.com/250x150'">Swap to smaller</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('image_swap')[0].src='http://via.placeholder.com/350x150'">Swap to larger</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding inline event is clumsy and it is against the separation of concern. Use `addEventListener` & add event to each of the button.Secondly `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a collection. So have to pass the index to add event to the specific element

```js
document.getElementById('smaller').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('image_swap')[0].src = 'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150'
});

document.getElementById('larger').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('image_swap')[0].src = 'http://via.placeholder.com/250x150'

})
```

```html
<h1>Image swapping</h1>
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="image_swap" /><br>

<button id="smaller">Swap to smaller</button>
<button id="larger">Swap to larger</button>
```